# Change textbox value when selecting dropdownlist value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net, textbox

I have a dropdownlist control that shows the primary key from a table called model, and a textbox that should show another value(a foreign key) from that same table when I use the dropdownlist.
Both PK  and FK have a single value.

Since I didn't have a clue how to do this, I used a search method that should be called everytime someone selects a new value from the dropdownlist.

Search code:

```
Public Function searchArea(ByVal model As String) As String

        Dim mycon As New Connection            

        Using connection As New SqlConnection(mycon.GetConnectionString())

            Using command As New SqlCommand()

                command.Connection = connection
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                command.CommandText = "SELECT area FROM model WHERE model= @model"
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", model)
                connection.Open()

                Dim dataReader As SqlDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

                If (dataReader.Read()) Then
                    Return dataReader.ToString(0)'this query should always have a single value
                End If

                Return "Nothing"

            End Using

        End Using

    End Function
```

Event code:

```
Protected Sub DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles DropDownList1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim objModel As New ModelDAO 'the class where the method is
        TextBox9.Text = objModel.searchArea(DropDownList1.Text)
    End Sub
```

.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True"
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="MODEL" DataValueField="MODEL">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="-Select-" Value="" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox9" runat="server" Enabled="False" Height="24px" 
                        Width="219px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DBUserInterfaceConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [MODEL] FROM [MODEL]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

But as I thought, it doesn't work, can you help me please?

EDIT: Thanks, now it triggers, but  I'm getting the value: 'S' that value doesn't belong to my table.Can you tell me if my search method is ok?

Comment: Is AutoPostBack set to TRUE?

Comment: Thanks, now it triggers, however i'm not getting the value I wanted, I guess I must check my sql sentence.

Comment: What is your SQL returning?

Comment: On another note... you should probably use AJAX on this site if you dont want the page to jump whenever they select an item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone, I solved it with this:

```
Return dataReader.GetString(0)
```

instead of:

```
Return dataReader.ToString(0)
```

It was just a type conversion problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1"   
    runat="server"   
    AutoPostBack="true"   
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">  
    .....
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to Load datareader into datatable and than use it to print data into the textbox..